# How to create a query that will call your view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created this view called [Vendors List] need help on creating a query that would call that vendors list here's the code for the `CREATE VIEW`:

```
CREATE VIEW [Vendors List] 
AS
    SELECT 
        VendorID, 
        SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS [YTD Invoice Total], 
        SUM(PaymentTotal) AS [YTD Payment Total], 
        SUM(CreditTotal) AS [YTD Credit Total]
    FROM 
        dbo.Invoices
    GROUP BY 
        VendorID
```

Comment: Create what query? What are you trying to do with this query?

Comment: this is sql server and not mysql

Comment: Sorry fellas what i meant to say is i have to create a query that would call my view that i created above display all the columns from that query above

Comment: You cannot "call" a view (since it's not really executable code, like a function or procedure) - you need to **select** from the view, like from a table

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe you created the view based on your question but here you go:

```
select * from [Vendors List]
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from ['Vendors List']